# How do you pronounce Yuan-ti?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, pronunciation, yuan-ti

I've heard Yuan-ti pronounced in various different ways by different people or video games (but some of these would have been English people and some would have been American, so there's that aspect to add some confusion to this as well).

For the first part–"Yuan"–I'd pronounce that something like "you-ahn". The obvious alternative is "you-an" (as in the name "Anne").

It's the last part–"ti"–that confuses me the most; is that "tee" or "tai"?

Is there an official canon pronunciation of Yuan-ti out there somewhere?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You-Ahn Tee

[Dndbeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/yuan-ti-pureblood) has the pronunciation as **You-Ahn Tee** when you select the audio clip.

---

This is also confirmed (Thanks NathanS!) in Dragon Magazine #93 in the "Ay pronunseeAYshun gyd" section on page 30. It's listed there as "yoo-an-TEE", which matches the audio clip from Dndbeyond.

As for the "an" part, on p. 24 of that magazine explains that:

> The letter A has several treatments. Short A (as in "far") is left alone, but long A (as in "fate") is always followed by Y ("fayt"). The narrow, back-of-the-throat A (as in "fat") is written as "@"–so that the word is "f@t."

So it seems that "an" matches up with the "ahn" that we hear in the audio clip.

Comment: I sometimes question the pronunciation guide since it says happen and gallop have different first vowels when in fact they are the same